# Web API error when retrieving file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to read and send xml file content from a web API. File is located in the disk.When I do the ReadStream,there is no breaking exceptions but if I open the response there are stream.ReadTimeout and stream.WriteTimeout errors.

This is the code I used:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var path = @"E:\files\1.xml";
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
        return result;
    }
```

Error is as follows:
[image]

**XML** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <fields xmlns:xfdf="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf-transition/"> <GenderListBox xfdf:original="Gender List Box">Man</GenderListBox> <Language5CheckBox xfdf:original="Language 5 Check Box">Off</Language5CheckBox> <Language4CheckBox xfdf:original="Language 4 Check Box">Off</Language4CheckBox> <Language3CheckBox xfdf:original="Language 3 Check Box">Yes</Language3CheckBox> <Language2CheckBox xfdf:original="Language 2 Check Box">Yes</Language2CheckBox> <Language1CheckBox xfdf:original="Language 1 Check Box">Off</Language1CheckBox> <FavouriteColourListBox xfdf:original="Favourite Colour List Box">Red</FavouriteColourListBox> <DrivingLicenseCheckBox xfdf:original="Driving License Check Box">Off</DrivingLicenseCheckBox> <HeightFormattedField xfdf:original="Height Formatted Field">150</HeightFormattedField> <FamilyNameTextBox xfdf:original="Family Name Text Box">ewew</FamilyNameTextBox> <GivenNameTextBox xfdf:original="Given Name Text Box">ewew</GivenNameTextBox> </fields>
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\files\1.xml")));
```

Comment: Giving a line of code to fix the issue is nice. Consider however adding some information on why this line would solve the issue, so OP and next readers will actually learn something if this fixes the problem.

Comment: dear @PAVITRA the above code works for me. if it doesn't for you i guess something is wrong with your xml file. please share your xml file so i can help you with it.

Comment: @David I have updated the question with the XML content.
Thanks